# Pasar el valor de un campo a una variable en Django

Tags: django

Tengo una aplicación en Django con un modelo de archivos subidos al servidor:

```
class Importar(models.Model):
""" Model per importar els arxius utilitzats per carregar els llistats de socis """

importar_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
importar_nom = models.CharField(max_length=100)
importar_data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
importar_ruta = models.FileField(verbose_name="Csv", upload_to="afadjango/arxius")

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Importar"
    verbose_name_plural = "Importacions"
```

En views.py tengo una clase que recibe la id de la instancia del modelo Importar y me gustaria poder pasar el campo importar_ruta a una variable para junto al BASE_DIR del proyecto pueda trabajar con este archivo subido al servidor. Pero no hay manera, este es el codigo de la classe que quiero que recupere la ruta del archivo y lo abra:

```
class ExempleImportacio(View):
""" Classe per mostrar la primera línia de dades a importar i permetre a l'usuari contralar aquesta importació """
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        socis = []
        id = self.kwargs['pk']
        importacio = Importar.objects.filter(importar_id=id).first()
        path = importacio.importar_ruta
        print(path)
        ruta = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, path)
        with open(ruta, "r") as csv_file:
```

Gracias por adelantado!